# Angular avoid code duplication when using `ng-if`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My current implementation:

```
<div class="outer-class" ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div class="inner-class" ng-if="isShow">
    <div class="inner-class-1">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!isShow" class="inner-class-1">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

The above code works, but there is a lot of code repetition:

1. `ng-if` is there twice (`ng-switch` cannot be used since a new element is introduced in between)
2. `<div ng-if="!isShow" class="inner-class-1">{{item}}</div>` is repeated twice, just because I do not want the element (`<div class="inner-class"></div>`) to encapsulate my data, when the `ng-if` evaluates to false.

I was wondering maybe if there is a better way to re-write the same.

Comment: You do not want the inner-class-1 element to be wrapped in another element all together or just not to have a parent with class inner-class?

Comment: I do not want the `inner-class-1` element to be present when my ng-if expression evaluates to false.

Comment: I think it would be better to refactor your CSS so the styling and behavior you want to toggle can be done so based on the existence of the `inner-class` class. I mean so the presence of the wrapping div doesn't make a difference at all, only the class itself should change things.

Comment: @ste2425 See the accepted answer. It was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you would better off creating a custom directive that could conditionally wrap contents. You could do something like this:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3];
  $scope.isShow = false;
})

.directive('wrapIf', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {

      var previousContent;

      scope.$watch(attrs.wrapIf, function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
          previousContent.parent().append(element);
          element.empty().append(previousContent);
        } else {
          transclude(function(clone, scope) {
            previousContent = clone;
            element.replaceWith(clone);
          });
        }
      })
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.inner-class, .inner-class-1 {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #DDD;
}
.inner-class-1 {
  background: #34dac3;
}
.outer-class {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">

  <p>
    <button ng-click="isShow = !isShow">Toggle isShow ({{ isShow }})</button>
  </p>

  <div class="outer-class" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="inner-class" wrap-if="isShow">
      <div class="inner-class-1" ng-click="test(item)">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a performance killer to use a watcher inside a `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: Not really if you use it wisely. ngIf does the same: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js But it's not about wrapIf directive, if's about how it used (not necessarily with ngRepeat) and what it does.

Comment: Oh yes, `::` - one time binding may help me here. `wrap-if="::isShow"`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```js
//optional wrapper

function resolveTemplate(tElement, tAttrs) {
  if (tAttrs.showWrapper){
    return "<div ng-class='wrapperClass' ng-transclude></div>"
  }
  else return "<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>";
}

app.directive('optionalWrapper', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: resolveTemplate,
        link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
          $scope.wrapperClass = attrs.wrapperClass;
        }
    };
});
```

To be used like this:

```html
<optional-wrapper wrapper-class='inner-class-1' show-wrapper='isShow'></optional-wrapper>
```

Comment: This solution will not work well, I guess. First of all, directive is not reusable, because template is hardcoded. Then, `show-wrapper` is used as an attribute which won't allow changing wrapping conditionally. Finally, it uses one more wrapper which is not very convenient for the directives purpose.